# getting errolist when using htmx and tinymce

Tags: javascript, python, django, tinymce, htmx

Im trying to implement post request with htmx and for rich text editor using tinymce.

my form :

```
    <!--<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}-->
    <form onsubmit='copyContent()' method= "post" hx-post= "{% url 'forum:forum-detail' post.pk %}" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-target = "#comment-list">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="threadTitle">Your Answer</label>
                <textarea name="reply" class="form-control summernote" placeholder="Input your answer here"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="cancelForm">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-post-question">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The error I get :

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>reply<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

it works just ok when I used the traditional post request with TinyMCE.

when I used htmx without TinyMCE its work just fine too.

it just when I combine htmx and TinyMCE I get the error.

my tinymce init:

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      body_id : "reply",
      height: 200,
      plugins: 'a11ychecker advcode casechange export formatpainter linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tinycomments tinymcespellchecker image code',
      toolbar: 'a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code export formatpainter pageembed permanentpen table image',
      toolbar_mode: 'floating',
      tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
      tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
   });
```

Comment: What does the `copyContent()` function do? Which TinyMCE version are you using?

Comment: @Dauros i think I use tinymce 5.  my other form has an editable input instead of textarea, since django form only recognize the textarea before submit i copy the innerhtml from editable to textarea. and then i tried to used the same method here to copy the textarea to the one that tinymce generate. Or i think that was the problem cause the iframe that generate doesn't have the same name, in this case 'reply'. But it seems that's not the one causes problem

Comment: You should try it first without any manual copying of the fields. I tried to reproduce your problem with a clean Django instance with [`django-tinymce`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-tinymce) package, but it was working fine out-of-the-box. The TinyMCE in the iframe synchronized the content of the editor with the textarea automatically, and HTMX was sending the correct form data.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar using Django, HTMX, and TincyMCE. It seems that the what ever event Tiny is triggering on form submit isn't being triggered when using the HTMX form event. My field isn't required, so I'm not seeing that error, but the <textarea></textarea> isn't getting updated when the HTMX form trigger event is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what solved this particular issue for me.

In this case the tinyMCE.triggerSave() method was not being triggered when the HTMX event fires. So what you need to do is call the method during one of your HTMX pre-request events. In this case I used htmx:configRequest event, however there may be better HTMX events to use.

Example:

```
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {

    // trigger the rich text editor save method
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    // update the parameter in request
    richContent = document.querySelector('#{{ your form field id}}');
    event.detail.parameters['{{ your form field name }}'] = richContent.value;
})
```

Because of the way the HTMX events fire, the form values have already been collected once the htmx:configRequest event fires, so you need to update the fields value in the request. There maybe some better ways of doing this, but this is working for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I'm pretty sure the reason is the order of the methods subscribed to the `submit` event of the form, as already explained by Dave.

I resolved adding a "blur" event callback on the tinyMCE editor that writes back the content of the editor to the textarea.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // ... other config parameters
    'setup': editor => {
       editor.on('blur', () => editor.save())
    }
})
```

I'm using tinyMCE 6.

Comment: Nothing else worked except for this, thank you!

Comment: Hands down this is great.

Answer (score 0):

i've done this, using the onfocus.

`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-id-submit" onfocus="tinyMCE.triggerSave();">`

probably triggered several times