# ckeditor not saving changes django

Tags: django, django-templates, ckeditor, htmx

I have a form where in one of the fields, I use the ckeditor. However when I submit the form, the changes in the ckeditor field is not being saved. In the model, I have changed the field to a`RichTextField`. I have installed "ckeditor" in my apps in settings as well.

I have also both tried to load these scripts in my template:

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js" %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %}"></script>
```

On top of that have I also tried to add the `{{ form.media }}` instead of the scripts but it does still not work.

I am using HTMX to dynamically update the form.

This is my form template right now

```
<form action='' method="POST" class="form" hx-post='' hx-swap='outerHTML'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    <div class="form-group">
    {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
     </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
   
    <br>

    <div class='htmx-indicator'>Loading...</div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class='htmx-inverted-indicator' type='submit' >Save</button>
      </div>
    
    {% if message %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    
</form>
```

Does anybody know why the form is not being saved?

**EDIT**
This is my view

```
@login_required
def book_update_view(request, id=None):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=id)
    form = BookForm(request.POST or None, instance=book)
       context = {
        "form": form,
         "object": book,
     }
    if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         context['message'] = 'Saved!'
    if request.htmx:
        return render(request, "book/snippets/forms.html", context)
    return render(request, "book/update.html", context)
```

Comment: If you can see the CKEditor, then perhaps it is not a problem with the template/form html, but with the saving process. Can you post the relevant code from your views.py /forms.py, please?

Comment: @SamSparx I added the the view

Comment: If you are not getting the 'saved' message then it is likely you have an invalid form.  Add error messages to your form as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/ under 'rendering form error messages' and see what that tells you.  If you do get the 'saved ' message, but the field isn't saving, check that it's not saved in admin either (so you know it's not a display issue).

Comment: @SamSparx I get the "Saved!" message. And when I try and display errors, no errors show up. The changes does not show up in admin either.

Comment: A couple of additional things to try to narrow down potential issues. Add a check for if request.method=="POST" before checking for form validity, and try removing the htmx elements from your template to see if the form saves successfully without them.

Comment: I removed hx-post from the form and it started working as it should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a conflict between the CKEditor and HTMX. The below relies heavily on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106253/django-ckeditor-modal-form-does-not-change-data-on-post). It makes the following changes:

- Switches the HTMX labels to the button rather than the form
- Applies an event
  listener to the CKEditor - it does this via the {{field.label_tag}}
  which is now included
- Fixes up a misplaced  tag

Try making your form something like this (don't forget to replace the name of the CKEditor field - you may need to check your source code to see how this is rendered):

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.media }}

<script>
document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) => {
    var element = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( document.getElementById( '{{ form.NAMEOFCKEDITORFIELD.id_for_label }}' ) );
    event.detail.parameters['{{ form.NAMEOFCKEDITORFIELD.html_name }}'] = element.getEditor().getData();        
})
</script>
<div class="form-group">
{% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}:<br />{{ field }}

{% endfor %}    
 </div>
<br>

<div class='htmx-indicator'>Loading...</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button class='htmx-inverted-indicator' type='submit' hx-post="{% url 'book_update_view_name' book.id %}" hx-target="#{{form.id}}" hx-swap="outerHTML">Save</button>
  </div>

{% if message %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The ckeditor changes does not work when I use HTMX, it refreshes the page. I have tried setting `hx-post` to both the url and having it empty and it does still not work. But when I do it without the HTMX, the ckeditor field works!

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. But may I ask why the HTMX tags are placed in the button tag rather than the form tag?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it matters functionally.  To me it's clearer that HTMX is overriding normal submit button behaviour but by all means try it the other way and see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want extra get parameter which might give you a problem, you can put onclick on your submit button to have ckeditor transfer the data to your field. something like this :

```
<script>
    function saveCK(){
             let ckdata = CKEDITOR.instances.your_field_id.getData();
             $('#your_field_id').val(ckdata);
          }
</script>
```

yeah, sorry for the jquery, I'm not sure vanilla javascript equivalent.

and on your submit button, add

```
onclick="saveCK()"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use hx-vals.

For example:

`<button type='submit' hx-vals="js:{ {{ form.NAMEOFCKEDITORFIELD.name }}: CKEDITOR.instances['{{ form.NAMEOFCKEDITORFIELD.id_for_label }}'].getData()}" hx-post=POSTURL>Save</button>`